# Find Shortest path in Java without defining the vertices/ nodes

Tags: java, path, dijkstra, indoor-positioning-system, shortest

I am trying to implement an Indoor Navigation System where I have to find the shortest path to a point from my present location.

Things I have reached to:
Using Dijkstra's Algorithm/ Hipster and a test code where I define 4 nodes with there weights and then try to find the shortest route from source to destination.

**Now the case is if suppose I am at a point on the map which is not defined as a node and I want to navigate to a point which may or may not be a node then in such case how to find the shortest path?**

Current test code I'am using:

```
package indoornav.shortestpath;

import java.util.List;

import es.usc.citius.hipster.algorithm.Hipster;
import es.usc.citius.hipster.graph.GraphBuilder;
import es.usc.citius.hipster.graph.GraphSearchProblem;
import es.usc.citius.hipster.graph.HipsterDirectedGraph;
import es.usc.citius.hipster.model.problem.SearchProblem;

public class Client3 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HipsterDirectedGraph<String,Double> graph = 
                GraphBuilder.<String,Double>create()
                 .connect("A").to("D").withEdge(10d)
                 .connect("A").to("C").withEdge(12d)
                 .connect("C").to("A").withEdge(12d)
                 .connect("C").to("B").withEdge(10d)
                 .connect("B").to("D").withEdge(10d)
                 .connect("B").to("C").withEdge(10d)
                 .connect("D").to("A").withEdge(10d)
                 .connect("D").to("B").withEdge(10d)

                 .createDirectedGraph();

            // Create the search problem. For graph problems, just use
            // the GraphSearchProblem util class to generate the problem with ease.
            SearchProblem p = GraphSearchProblem
                                       .startingFrom("A")
                                       .in(graph)
                                       .takeCostsFromEdges()
                                       .build();

            // Search the shortest path from "A" to "F"
            System.out.println(Hipster.createDijkstra(p).search("B"));
    }
}

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find shortest path between two neighbor nodes of where you located and where you need located. Then need add to result a path from your real location to start node and from target location to target node:

```
A` - real location
A  - start node(neighbor for A`)
B` - target location
B  - target node(neighbor for B`)

result = shortest(A,B) + (A`-A) + (B`-B)
```

Comment: HI slesh, thanks for the answer but can you please explain it or give some reference link to it. I' am new to these algorithm and fundamentals.
A few lines code for reference would help much better :-)